# Converting columns into a Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Target outcome: [image: Target Outcome]

I'm new to pandas/python - I've managed to create a multi index for the Country and Job Group data as shown in the columns.

I transposed the data frame so that I could work on the 'Years' and 'Group by Sex' and turn those into a multi-index as well. I've reclassified them as categories but still couldn't turn them into a multi-index.

Comment: does this help you? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html